# check input from console

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read user input in console and check if file or folder exists without them entering full path?
This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter file/folder: ");
      String input = scan.nextLine();
      File fileIn = new File(input);

      while (!fileIn.exists())  {

        System.out.print("File/folder does not exit! Enter another: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        fileIn = new File(input);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [java.nio.files.File.exists(Path,LinkOption)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-).

In your case the usage for this method would be:

```
Path file;
do {
   file = Paths.get(scan.nextLine());
} while(!Files.exists(file));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs if a relative path is given it is resolved against the user director.

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory.